# How does the "delivery of baggage in connection" work with VivaAerobús?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, layovers, mexico, viva-aerobus

I saw a "delivery of baggage in connection" desk with VivaAerobús at MEX airport.  How does it work? Is it to retrieve one's checked in luggage during a layover or stopover? If so, does one have to request the luggage retrieval before taking the first leg of the flight?

[image]

Comment: Is this in the check-in area? I would think this is rather a baggage drop for international to domestic connections: you retrieve your luggage when you land, go through customs, and drop it there (it’s probably already tagged for the final destination). A bit like in the US, but less convenient (in the US that baggage drop is usually just after customs). See https://www.vivaaerobus.com/en-us/info/about-us/connecting-flights the “International Connection” section.

Comment: @jcaron yes.  Thanks, got it, makes sense, so the  delivery is from the passengers to the airline employees, and  not the  contrary as I had first thought when reading the screen, right?

Comment: It seems like "delivery" is a not-great translation of [_entrega_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/entrega#Noun_2) here; something like "dropoff" would be more idiomatic in English, but I'd happily forgive the mild error in a case like this in a country where English is not the local language

Comment: @mlc thanks! You and jcaron are welcome to post your comments as answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll summarize the answer that this question received in the comment section: what VivaAerobús calls "delivery of baggage in connection" at MEX airport is simply a baggage drop for international to domestic connections where passengers retrieve their luggage when they land, go through the Mexican customs, and drop it there at the place where the OP took the picture.

The same happens in the US, e.g. if flying NRT -> LAX -> SAN: the passengers will have to retrieve their checked-in luggage when they land at LAX airport, go through the US customs, and drop off their checked-in luggage before flying from LAX to SAN.

VivaAerobús didn't translate properly [*entrega*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/entrega#Noun_2): they translated it into delivery instead of "dropoff", which would have been clearer.

---

Comments:

> - Is this in the check-in area? I would think this is rather a baggage drop for international to domestic connections: you retrieve your luggage when you land, go through customs, and drop it there (it’s probably already tagged for the final destination). A bit like in the US, but less convenient (in the US that baggage drop is usually just after customs). See [vivaaerobus.com/en-us/info/about-us/connecting-flights](https://www.vivaaerobus.com/en-us/info/about-us/connecting-flights) the “International Connection” section. 
>   [jcaron](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30703/jcaron) [Jan 5 at 22:40](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/171592/how-does-the-delivery-of-baggage-in-connection-work-with-vivaaerob%c3%bas#comment427727_171592)
> - It seems like "delivery" is a not-great translation of [*entrega*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/entrega#Noun_2) here; something like "dropoff" would be more idiomatic in English, but I'd happily forgive the mild error in a case like this in a country where English is not the local language [mlc](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/94507/mlc) [Jan 5 at 22:54](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/171592/how-does-the-delivery-of-baggage-in-connection-work-with-vivaaerob%c3%bas#comment427731_171592).